# flask conditional inserting of script based on url

Tags: python, flask

I want to conditionally add a script using flask's built if else template tags

If i'm on my funding page I would like to insert my funding script

for example:

```
{% if url == '/funding' %}
    <script src="{{ url_for ('static', filename='js/funding.js')}}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if url_for == 'funding' %}
        <script src="{{ url_for ('static', filename='js/funding.js')}}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

setting the context throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1994, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/darren/PycharmProjects/schoolDonations/schoolDonations.py", line 22, in funding
    return render_template("funding.html", url_for='funding')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 116, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/darren/PycharmProjects/schoolDonations/templates/funding.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "index.html" %}
  File "/Users/darren/PycharmProjects/schoolDonations/templates/index.html", line 5, in top-level template code
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for ('static',
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__call__'
```

Comment: ok sure ... just set the context...

Comment: please can you elaborate?

Comment: `renter_template('my_template.html',url_for='funding')`

Comment: Neither Python nor Djinja templates have a `===` operator.

Comment: @KlausD I have edited the template to change operator to `==` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @JoranBeasley I have edited the first post to show error thrown when context is set

Comment: dont name it `url_for` ... just pass it `is_funding=True` or whatever ... you are gonna have to connect these dots on your own

Answer (score 3):

You can obviously do that. I assume that you are using the same template in multiple routes and want to load a JS file in a specific route. You can do this like following:

`application.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def show_index():
    return render_template('funding.html')

@app.route('/funding')
def show_funding():
    return render_template('funding.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

We can use `{{ request.path }}` in template which returns the relative path of the current request. The template `funding.html` contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>You are here: {{ request.path }}</h3>
    {% if request.path == url_for('show_funding') %}
        <script src="{{ url_for ('static', filename='js/funding.js')}}"></script>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

The JS file (`funding.js`) located in `js` which is in `static` folder. It contains a single alert message:

```
alert("Hello from funding page");
```

Now when we visit the root path the JS file is not loaded but when we visit the `funding` path it is being loaded like this:

[image: load js dynamically in template]